# Change WooCommerce Product Permalink Structure

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce, permalinks

According to my suppliers they want the local site and the international site to have the same product URL's just different domain. However my site is built on WooCommerce and there's is a custom PHP integration.

I have been haggling for days to try and get this to work by htaccess (I'm no Pro) and via a custom Permalinks plug-in without any luck.

I'm not sure if it is possible but I need the URL structure to be like this:

**From:** https://localhost.za/artnr/10616/
**To:** https://localhost.za/?artnr=10616

I have tried via the htaccess file, Like I said I'm no pro and have also tried with a custom Permalink plug-in without luck. I know I could probably get around this with creating a custom product page, but I would lose a lot of functionality

Comment: To clarify your question, please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below in your htaccess:

```htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^artnr/(\d+)/?$ /?artnr=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`^artnr/` - This part of the pattern matches the starting part of the URL you want to rewrite.

`(\d+)` - This is a capturing group that matches one or more digits (the product number in your case) and captures it.

`/?$` - This matches an optional trailing slash at the end of the URL.

`/?artnr=$1` - This is the substitution part of the rewrite. It replaces the matched URL with the desired format, including the query string parameter artnr and its value.

This therefore should give you the desired URL of https://localhost.za/?artnr=10616

Comment: This makes the _assumption_ that URLs of the form `/?artnr=<num>` are valid on the current site. But this also doesn't actually _change_ the public URL, which would seem to be the intention here.